# MVC ViewModel Error - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to know how can I use my ViewModel on the Create Action? I tried several examples I found here in the forum, but none solved my problem. I've been racking my brain for a few days, but can't figure out what is wrong.

Whenever I click the Create button I get the following error:
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

```
@model MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.AlbumViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Album</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumItem.GenreId, "Genre")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Genres", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumItem.GenreId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumItem.ArtistId, "Artist")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Artists", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumItem.ArtistId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumItem.Price)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumItem.AlbumArtUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumItem.AlbumArtUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumItem.AlbumArtUrl)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Create.cshtml

```
    public class StoreManagerController : Controller
        {
            private MusicStoreDB db = new MusicStoreDB();

            //
            // GET: /StoreManager/Create

            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                var viewModel = new AlbumViewModel()
                {
                    Genres = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name"),
                    Artists = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name")
                };
                return View(viewModel);
            } 

            //
            // POST: /StoreManager/Create

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(AlbumViewModel vm)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Albums.Add(vm.AlbumItem);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                }

                vm.Genres = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", vm.AlbumItem.GenreId);
                vm.Artists = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", vm.AlbumItem.ArtistId);
                return View(vm);
            }
}
```

StoreManager.cs - Snippet

```
public class AlbumViewModel
    {
        public AlbumViewModel()
        {
            //  nothing
        }

        public Album AlbumItem { get; set; }
        public SelectList Genres { get; set; }
        public SelectList Artists { get; set; }
    }

public class Album
    {
        public Album()
        {
            //  nothing
        }

        public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }

public class Artist
    {
        public Artist()
        {
            // nothing
        }

        public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class Genre
    {
        public Genre()
        {
            // nothing
        }

        public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Added `Genre` and `Artist` on the code above.

Comment: The only thing that seems to not have a parameterless constructor is the SelectList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx). What if you comment those?

Comment: @fvss - What is the constructor for new MusicStoreDB()?  Also, you should probably post the stack trace (yellow screen) as that will give you the line the error was thrown at

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I had a nickel for every time I've seen this problem.  It's typically related to the naming of your model properties and how you use them in a `DropDownList`.  99.999% of the time it's because people are using `Html.DropDownList()` and naming it the same as their `SelectList`.  This is one reason you should use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor`.

In this case, your problem is that you have `SelectList`s named `Genres` and `Artists`, then in your view you have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Genres", String.Empty)
@Html.DropDownList("Artists", String.Empty)
```

See, same name.

What you should do is change your Model to make the `SelectList`s be named `GenreList` and `ArtistList`.  Then, change your view to use strongly typed model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AlbumItem.GenreID, Model.GenreList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AlbumItem.ArtistID, Model.ArtistList)
```

The reason this happens is that you are posting a value called Genres to the controller.  The default model binder dutifully looks in the model to find something called Genres and instantiate it.  But, rather than an ID or string, it finds a SelectList named Genres, and when it tries to instantiate it, it finds there is no default constructor.

Thus your error.  SO is filled with questions asking about this same thing.

Comment: Same here. You saved my several hours

Comment: Also can occur when using model object which is used in webform and do not have parameterless  constructor in it as it happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Erik Funkenbusch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12701768/413180) I'd added a DropDownList to my form, however in my case it wasn't (and wasn't intended to be) submitted with the form as it was outside of the `<form></form>` tags:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myField", Model.MyField)
```

As the Model contained the field for display only, this also caused the `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error because the field wasn't submitted at all.

In this case I fixed it by adding an exclude binding:

```
public ActionResult Foo(int id, int? page, [Bind(Exclude = "MyField")]MyModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in the BeginForm() method itself. It looked like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAccount", "MyController", Model))
```

Copied and pasted in from another project's Login page, which doesn't have a dropdown.

Anyway, remove the Model from the parameter list and it all works just fine :)