# Pass ViewModal from javascript file to code-behind

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Javascript file that calls a method in my code-behind.  This seems to work if I create a parameterless default constructor, EXAMPLE 1, BUT I want to pass to the save method my ViewModel, EXAMPLE 2. When I do this I get a 500 error.  After digging deeper I discovered more details about that network error.

Parameterless Default Constructor - this works but only if the other constructor is commented out.

EXAMPLE 1

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveWorkRequestDetails()
{
    return Json(new {});
}
```

If I have both of these in the code-behind file then I get this error:  The current request for action 'SaveWorkRequestDetails' on controller type 'WorkRequestController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult SaveWorkRequestDetails() on type WorkRequest.Controllers.WorkRequestController
System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult SaveWorkRequestDetails(WorkRequest.ViewModel.WorkRequestViewModel) on type WorkRequest.Controllers.WorkRequestController

EXAMPLE 2

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveWorkRequestDetails(WorkRequestViewModel viewModel)
{
    // TODO: Save logic goes here
    return Json(new { });
}
```

I need to pass the viewModel in order to save the user's selections.  I am missing something and I am not sure what.

```
RegisterUIEventHandlers: function () {
    $('#Save').click(function (e) {
        // Check whether the form is valid. Note: Remove this check, if you are not using HTML5
        if (document.forms[0].checkValidity()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: WorkRequest.SaveUrl,
                data: ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // Display loading image
                    alert(ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel));
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Handle the response here.
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // Hide loading image.
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Handle error.
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In the alert you see in beforeSend, in the AJAX POST within the javascript above, I see the selections the user makes.  Everything works so I just want to pass this to the Controller's SaveWorkRequestDetails, how can I do this please.  I was my understanding that the data parameter passed this on to the method specified in the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You have two action methods with the same name. So, call to the `SaveWorkRequestDetails` is ambigious as the error indicates.

You can overload functions in C# but it is not possible in ASP.NET MVC Framework.

It is not possible to have two `SaveWorkRequestDetails()` actions with different method signatures on the same controller in ASP.NET MVC.

Just remove the first `SaveWorkRequestDetails()`, and you will be fine.

Comment: I added the one without any parameters because the EXAMPLE 2 never got called.  Ideally I just want the Save method you see as the second example.

Comment: By never called, do you mean WorkRequestViewModel is null or, the ajax is request never sent ?

Comment: I mean I place a breakpoint there and it is never reached.  If I only have the Save method in Example 2 I get a different error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: I had a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700943/mvc-viewmodel-error-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object and changed my Index.cshtml to: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkSections.SelectedValue, Model.WorkSections, "--> Select Item <--", new {id = "ddlWorkSections"}) and I get the same exact result.

Comment: Ok, I now have the Save method in Example # 2 being called but my ViewModel is null.  Not sure why but I've solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the dataType to json instead of application/json.  This resolved the issue of the error stating there was not a parameterless default constructor.  Now SaveWorkRequestDetails is being called.

```
RegisterUIEventHandlers: function () {
    $('#Save').click(function (e) {
        // Check whether the form is valid. Note: Remove this check, if you are not using HTML5
        if (document.forms[0].checkValidity()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: WorkRequest.SaveUrl,
                data: ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // Display loading image
                    alert(ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel));
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Handle the response here.
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // Hide loading image.
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Handle error.
                }
            });
        }
    });
```