# Error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." with SelectList from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my viewmodel I made two SelectList properties with names of cities coming from an external database.

ViewModel

```
namespace Treinreizen.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ReizenViewModel
    {
        public SelectList VanStad { get; set; }

        public SelectList NaarStad { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller I use one GET method "Registratie" where the user can select cities and one POST method to post this cities. The problem is that I get the error

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

when I try to post my form. In the Stack Trace it says:

> "[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]" and "[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.]"

Controller

```
        // GET: Hotels/Registratie
        public ActionResult Registratie()
        {
            stedenServices = new StedenServices();
            ReizenViewModel registratieviewmodel = new ReizenViewModel();
            registratieviewmodel.VanStad = new SelectList(stedenServices.All(), "StadID", "Stad");
            registratieviewmodel.NaarStad = new SelectList(stedenServices.All(), "StadID", "Stad");
            return View(registratieviewmodel);
        }

        // POST: Hotels/Registratie
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registratie(ReizenViewModel registratie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(registratie);
        }
```

View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VanStad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VanStad, Model.VanStad, "--Selecteer Stad--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VanStad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NaarStad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NaarStad, Model.NaarStad, "--Selecteer Stad--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NaarStad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701768/920557

Comment: This is not MVVM, it's MVC, hence "asp.net-**mvc**".ReizenViewModel isn't a view model, that's a model.  You're mixing up two different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameterless constructor to ReizenViewModel that does nothing:

```
public ReizenViewModel(){}
```